# While routing to a secondary outlet, can I use a string as the named outlet?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing

I am building a system that has dynamic content being routed to using secondary (named) router outlets.

**Example:**

*HTML*

```
<div id="col1'>
   <router-outlet name="col1"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div id="col2'>
   <router-outlet name="col2"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

*TypeScript*

```
for (let c of this.containers) {
   switch (c.containerKey) {
     case "col1":
        this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { col1: [c.id] } }]);
       break;
     case "col2":
         this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { col2: [c.id] } }]);
         break;
   }
}
```

Is it possible to remove the switch case and use `c.containerKey` as the named outlet?

**Example**

```
for (let c of this.containers) {
   this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { c.containerKey: [c.id] } }]);
}
```

I know the above example **DOES NOT** work. But Is there a way to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with computed property names by adding [ ] around c.containerKey like so:

```
this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { [c.containerKey]: [c.id] } }]);
```